# How to edit the header of a huge CSV file in-place?

Tags: unix, csv, perl

I have several huge CSV files in which I want to swap two column names.

I do **not** want to *modify/copy/rewrite* the data.

The operation is very cheap in `C`: `fopen` the file, `fgets` the header, `fseek` or `rewind`, manipulate the header (*preserving its length*), `fputs` the new header, `fclose` the file.

This can also be done in `ANSI Common Lisp` ([CLISP](http://clisp.org), [SBCL](http://sbcl.org) or [GCL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcl/)):

```
 (with-open-file (csv "foo.csv" :direction :io
                      :if-exists :overwrite)
   (let ((header (read-line csv)))
     (print header)
     (file-position csv 0)
     (write-line (string-upcase header) csv)
     (file-position csv 0)
     (read-line csv)))
```

and takes *a fraction of a second* (`sed` takes *a few minutes* because it reads and re-writes the whole file even it you tell it to modify just the first line, ignoring the crucial information that the size of the header did *not* change).

How do I do that with the "standard unix tools" (e.g., `perl`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not know the length of the header, `head -n1` seems like a reasonable way to get the first line.

To write it in-place back to the head of the file, you can use dd:

```
head -n1 file.csv | ./do-some-processing | dd of=file.csv bs=1 conv=notrunc
```

the `conv=notrunc` is critical to leave the rest of the file intact, and `bs=1` is to stop on byte boundary.

Comment: Nice, I never knew about notrunc.  But note that ./do-some-processing must preserve the length of the header (as specified by the OP.)  Just a warning for tl;dr folks (like me :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest `sed` for this, you can specify to only make the substitution on the first line such as `1s/foo/bar/`:

```
$ cat file
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
3,2,1
...

$ sed -e '1s/col1/tmp/' -e '1s/col3/col1/'  -e '1s/tmp/col3/' file
col3,col2,col1
1,2,3
3,2,1
...
```

Use `-i` to store the change back to the file:

```
$ sed -i -e '1s/col1/tmp/' -e '1s/col3/col1/'  -e '1s/tmp/col3/' file
```

Comment: This does modify the file as required, but this re-writes the data, i.e., `time` shows that the `sed` command takes about the same time (few minutes) as `cp`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to swap two words, then all you need is in-place rewriting of a few bytes.

This is an easy task for a commandline hexadecimal editor.

I would recommend `hexedit` which I just used to edit a 30 Gb `.csv` file. The time spent on opening/saving the file was negligible (less than a second). In fact, my time was mostly spent looking up its [keyboard shortcuts](http://rigaux.org/hexedit.html)... (`TAB` to switch to ASCII display, `Ctrl-X` to save and exit).

Comment: The idea was to use a batch, not an interactive, process.

Answer (score -1):

Or maybe "head" the file to remove the first line to a separate file.

Then change the heading file and merge the two back together.

Comment: this copies the data, i.e., the time spent is proportional to the data size.

Comment: So why mark this down and accept the same answer above?

Comment: because the answer above is constant in time and this answer is not

Comment: In all fairness, you didn't explain how to merge the files together. Using `dd` was the non-trivial insight.